# Registering handler for unhandled exceptions

Tags: ruby, exception

Is it possible to define an exception handler for any unhandled exceptions? Wrapping my entire code block in a begin/rescue/end block feels messy.

Comment: Hmm, code that could throw an exception out of any place feels messy too, no?

Comment: @maerics I suppose so in some cases, but imagine if you needed to catch showstopping unhandled exceptions (read: bugs) in a daemon that needed to cleanly shut itself down and send a notification.

Comment: i think wrapping your entire code in begin/rescue end is the way to go, and shouldn't feel messy. factor the real work out into it's own method, so you just have one 'main' method to wrap or something. `begin ; executeCode() ; rescue`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using at_exit? It should be called even when an exception occurs and you can log the last exception using $!

Here is an example:

```
at_exit {
puts "Last exception: (#{$!.inspect})"
puts "Backtrace: \n#{$@}"
puts "Exiting..."
}

puts "my app..."
raise "Exception!"
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit

Comment: That's originally how I implemented it but I made a bad assumption about the value of $! and overlooked this thinking there must be a better way. This is the correct solution, although it's necessary to call `kind_of?` on `$!` in order to check whether the exception is `SystemExit` which is expected as a result of a call to `exit`.