# Is there a way to alter the way error messages are displayed?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I want to alter the way error messages and their backtrace are displayed without `rescue`-ing the errors and calling a custom method. Is there a way to do this? Is there a method that is called when error messages are displayed which can be overridden? If it is a built-in part of Ruby, can someone point me to the relevant C code that formats the error messages and the backtrace?

Comment: it's an interesting question but, out of curiosity, why protecting the main method of the script with a begin/rescue block is not an option?

Comment: @tokland Because I want that to be a default behavior for any Ruby script that I write. I don't want to bother writing `rescue` for every Ruby script. At least, I would have to include the relevant file that makes the modification, though.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521559/registering-handler-for-unhandled-exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matugm's answer to a question that samuil linked pointed me to the way. I can do this:

```
at_exit do
  print_the_altered_error_message($!) if $! and !$!.kind_of?(SystemExit)
  $stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
end
```

This will not be effective for syntax errors, but for most other cases, it will work.